# MongoDB Ignoring Filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb-query

Either I'm missing something or is this a possible Node.js driver issue?

```js
const users = await User.find({ 'test.test': { $gt: 0 } }).lean();
```

None of my User documents contain the `test` object, therefore none should meet this filter's criteria. However, instead of returning no documents, it's returning all of my user documents. According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#mongodb-method-db.collection.find), it should only ever return all of the documents in a collection if no/empty filters are passed?

*Edit:* I said ignoring filter as it only seems to occur when applying nested filters on undefined properties. For instance, if I add more filter conditions that a few documents meet they'll apply *correctly.
Example: `User.find({ username: { $exists: true }, 'test.test': { $gt: 0 } })` returns only the user documents where `username` exists, however they still don't have the `test` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by setting the Mongoose Schema `strictQuery` option to false.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strictQuery